# Where can I see how Haskell modules have been restructured?

Tags: haskell

Since the recent update of Haskell on my system, I'm getting numerous import errors. For example, I get:

```
Crypto/Enigma.hs:64:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Data.List.Split’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
64 | import           Data.List.Split        (splitOn)
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Crypto/Enigma.hs:70:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Data.String.Utils’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
70 | import           Data.String.Utils       (replace)
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is there a place I can go to see what changes have been made to the package structure in the recent update? Im particular, where the functions I'm looking for have gone (to what modules)?

Comment: Not sure which recent update you're referring to. These errors seem to indicate you are missing some dependencies to your project. `Data.List.Split` is from `split` package. `Data.String.Utils` appears to be from `MissingH`. Do you have those installed? Are you using haskell platform, stack or nix?

Comment: Use your build tool to query which version of the package you are using, then look at the documentation for that version of the package (which is often installed locally on your machine - the location will depend on which build tool you are using).

Comment: You're talking about updating GHC, right? If so, I believe you have to reinstall your packages. I don't think there's a way around that, since different versions of GHC probably can't really be guaranteed to generate code that is compatible (down to the object file level).